# Fedora 18: Can not find version.h

Tags: fedora, display-driver

I am attempting to install some ATI graphics drivers. The installer fails and the log says this:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.8.4-202.fc18.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

Now my question is simple: what package(s) do I need to obtain the header file? I am assuming it is a Linux source package (which I have already installed). Another problem is that by going to `/lib/modules/3.8.4-202.fc18.x86_64/build` appears to be an orphan symlink.

Comment: I edited your question to try to make the log output a little more readable; please check it to make sure I didn’t get it wrong.  Also, what do you mean by “orphan symlink”?

Comment: orphan symbolic link, a link to the file that no longer exists (like a shortcut in windows)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `kernel-devel` package (and all it requires) for the *running* kernel to be able to build modules for it. And rebuild it each time.

Note that Fedora uses new kernels and X, it has often happened that third party/vendor modules trail behind and just don't work.